# Parse.com push broadcast disabled - "You have no registered installations of your app"

Tags: parse-platform, push

Parse push broadcast feature had stopped working suddenly.

When clicking on "Send a Push" button it tells me :

"You have no registered installations of your app. You can get started with our Quick Start guide."

I have more than 35K app installations and used to send push to all of them.

What just happened?

Answer (score 0):

Parse has seemed very slow today, and if you look at their support page there are a lot of people complaining about timeouts.  I would report the issue, but my guess is that things will return back to normal on their own.  This happens with parse a lot.. although their page always says all systems operational...